# How do I solve this Sinusoidal Function word problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If a nail is caught in the tire of a bicycle. The height (in metres) of the nail is represented by the graph below. If the nail finally fell out after 6 periods, how long was the nail stuck in the tire (in seconds)?

[The graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbX9w.png)

Comment: You know length travelled over a period and the number of periods, so if you know the speed you can work it out too

Comment: @HenryLee I know, but I can't solve it, can you show me how? Thank you.

Comment: well do you know the velocity of the bike

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is not a full answer, but there are a few things we can take away from the graph:

Firstly, the maximum displacement (if we neglect length of the nail) will represent the diameter of the wheel, giving $D=10\text{units}$. I assume this is what the $y$ represents, however I am not sure what the $x$ represents (distance travelled?) although this does not feel correct as it would insinuate the diameter and circumference be the same, so:

What is $x$? What other values/constants are you given?